# How I can get all categories and subcategories?

Tags: magento, navigation, categories

How I can get all categories and subcategories if the category is active, but "Include in Navigation Menu" is set to "No"?

I try to use this:

```
<?php 
$_categories = Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/navigation'); 
foreach ($_categories->getStoreCategories() as $_category) { 
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category'); 
$category->load($_category->getId()); 
$subcategories = explode(',', $category->getChildren()); 
?> 
<dl> 
<dt><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()); ?></dt> 
<dd> 
<ol> 
<?php 
foreach ($subcategories as $subcategoryId) { 
$category->load($subcategoryId); 
echo '<li><a href="' . $category->getURL() . '">' . $category->getName() . '</a></li>'; 
} 
?> 
</ol> 
</dd> 
</dl> 
<?php

} 
?>
```

But if a category's “Include in Nav menu" is "No”, it won't show on the front page!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You only need to change one thing! When you call `$_categories = Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/navigation')` you're actually grabbing the categories from the `catalog/navigation` model specifically - the filtering out of "non navigation" categories is already complete. Instead, we can grab a collection from the `catalog/category` model to make sure we get all categories available on the site:

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addIsActiveFilter();
```

Note that I am using `addIsActiveFilter()` to make sure we only get categories that are currently active / enabled.

Comment: Thanks, you really helped! Displays what is necessary, then I will bring it as it should be!

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use the catalog/category helper

```
$helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
$categories = $helper->getStoreCategories();
```

Comment: I got nothing,  $helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
            $categories = $helper->getStoreCategories(); foreach ($categories as $_category) {
                print_r($_category->getName()); die(); }